# Performance and Functionality Difference between log4j and Logging Util class

Tags: java, logging, log4j, error-logging, java.util.logging

I am newbie for the logging class in Java.util package, I have developed an Application and want to implement the logging mechanism at different levels, I am just thinking to which one to go for and identify the differences between these 2.
I am looking
1) logger should be easily maintainable, implementable.
Can any one suggest on this.

Answer (score 5):

`java.util.logging` is a poor API, on top of a poor implemention. Log4j is better in every measurable way.

If it's a new development, though, then there are better APIs than log4j, such as [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), and better logging implementations, such as [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). I would try those. Log4j is getting a bit long in the tooth, but it's perfectly serviceable.

Comment: SLF4J is actually a logging **facade** so that one can switch between different logging implementations (e.g. util logging, log4j, logback etc) without modifying the code.

Comment: Yes, that's why I called it an API :)